# Is it good practice to have boolean "recursiveCall" parameter in a function?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a function which calls itself, but to avoid infinite recursion when the function is calling itself I pass a boolean variable so it does not call itself again. However this also means someone using my code can use the function and pass it a `true` argument.

```
class Test
{
public:
  static bool doCheck(int x, bool recursiveCall = false)
private:
  int m_array {10, 5, 3, 25, 12, 0, -6};
  int tracker = 0;
};

bool Test::doCheck(int x, bool recursiveCall)
{
  if (m_array[tracker] > x)
  {
    //do stuff
    ++tracker;
    return true;
  }
  else if (!recursiveCall)
  {
    // reset tracker 
    tracker = 0;
    return doCheck(x, true);
  }

  return false;
}

int main()
{
  Test::doCheck(2); // returns true, m_array[tracker] now equals 5

  // The next call will go through the "else if" part which will reset the tracker
  // and return false, if we didn't call the function as recursive it would call itself infinitely !
  Test::doCheck(50);


  return 0;
}
```

Edit: As requested I provided a better example. Of course we could perform the `m_array[tracker] > x` before calling doCheck() again but it means our check will be done twice, and it can be problematic if we check some things using a more complex algorithm

Is it good practice to do that?

Comment: If you have to use such "trick" to avoid infinite recursion, it probably indicates that your function is wrongly designed. Recursive function usually have a "trivial" case, which does not recurse, and all recursive calls tend to this "trivial" case. In your example, the trivial case is when `x` is bigger than 10, but the recursive calls tend to decrese `x`... So if `x` was not bigger than 10 in the first place, it will never be bigger than 10 after decreasing it, so your `else` block adds nothing to  your function.

Comment: Moreover, if you know that you call this function twice, and always twice, why do you  need recursion in the first place? Just call the second implementation function.

Comment: So it is better to have twice the "same" function with one that is only meant to be called by the original one ?

Comment: @Matt Could you provide an example of a function that would requires such structure? I cannot think of any decent function that would require such behaviour.

Comment: Okay, I will post a better example in an hour or so

Comment: @Matt I spent 30s trying to figure out what your code does... And then I gave up. More seriously, I still don't see the point of such function. You want to check, and if the check fails, you reset your tracker, and you check the first one? I can think of context where you would like to reset in case of failure, but you would let the next call check after reset, in which case the recursive call would not be necessary. As I said, if you have a function where you need such "trick", it's probably wrong by design, as is this example.

Comment: @Matt By the way, when your say *"Of course we could perform the m_array[tracker] > x before calling doCheck() again but it means our check will be done twice, and it can be problematic if we check some things using a more complex algorithm"*, this is already the case... If `m_array[tracker] > x` fails, then you are going to check `m_array[0] > x` right after, so you do not gain anything by making a recursive call instead of checking again in the `else` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's a bad idea. Instead re-write your base case so that it will always stop on it's own.

Your example is never going to sensibly recurse, so it may as well be

```
void foo(int x)
{
    if (x > 10)
    { /* Do stuff here */ }
}
```